# Why does an Esri Extent load for one map layer but not for another? ArcGIS Javascript API

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, esri

I am having the weirdest problem right now using the ArcGIS Javascript API (v2.4). I'm merely trying to create an instance of an ESRI topo map with an extent, and then add a layer.

Here is the code that works. I create an extent, then a map, then a streetmap layer and then finally add that layer.

```
var startExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent(-71.5, 42, -71, 42.5, new esri.SpatialReference({wkid:4326}) );
map = new esri.Map("map_canvas", { extent: startExtent,fitExtent:false });
var streetmap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer");
map.addLayer(streetmap);
```

However when I try and do the same thing with a separate server, it doesn't work.

```
var startExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent(-71.5, 42, -71, 42.5, new esri.SpatialReference({wkid:4326}) );
map = new esri.Map("map_canvas", { extent: startExtent,fitExtent:false });
var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer");
map.addLayer(basemap);
```

I know that the faulty-layer's server works, because if I create a map with no extent, it shows the full world imagery server, so it appears that creating a map in with one layer and an extent works, while creating a map with a different layer but the same extent does not work.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, the layer is in **web Mercator**.

Try converting the extent from **geographic** to **web Mercator** before using it in the map constructor.

The easiest way to convert the extent is to use `esri..geometry.geographicToWebMercator`.